# Dropbox sync using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm having quite an annoying issue. I'd like to begin developing an iOS app, but I'd rather not learn Object-C due to time. I'm looking at PhoneGap, but have one issue.

If possible, I'd also like to sync the data across multiple devices. I'd rather not use a remote database, as I have no idea what the expected amount of users will be, and therefore no idea how much bandwidth I will need for a MySQL database. Is it possible to save data to txt files, then upload them to Dropbox using JavaScript (and all on PhoneGap)?

Comment: You should have a more descriptive title.

Comment: And you need to ask just one question, not several.

Comment: @JosephSilber hopefully fixed - well, still to many subquestions to match.

Answer (score 1):

Really i think learning the language is a relatively simpler challenge. It's learning the API itself that will take time, and you will have that issue regardless of where you go. If you prefer the javascript syntax, i know there is [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). But given the features you want, I think learning objective-c is the way to go, because there are so many resources for using the API. I know of a few apps that use Dropbox as storage. Byword is one of them.

Depending on the app you are building, dropbox with flat files might suit your needs. If you need something more customizable, then you may need to build a remote db server. Though understand that sync is hard.

Comment: I was about to up vote your answer - but then I noticed that would destroy your leet score :D ...